# Web Part Zones/Web Parts not rendered on page in Firefox

Tags: publishing-site, page-layout

I am currently working on building out publishing site and since yesterday having issues with Firefox.   We have pretty simple layouts that have a main Page Content Region and underneath this region several zones that pages use for CQWPs etc.

The issue is that in Firefox,  We only see the main page content area an no zones below.  It is like the page just cuts off.  In IE 8 and chrome the page is fine.

I can't trace back what might of caused this issue.  Reverting back to an older version of a page didnt help.

Any guidance for troubleshooting would be much appreciated.

Paul

Answer (score 1):

So I would use the following tools to debug the display of the page and the correctness of any javascript

- [Web Developer add on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/)
- [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/)

Key things to look for:

- Validate that the html you want to display has actually been downloaded
- Remove all CSS styling to see if the page renders the content
- Slowly "enable" each css file one by one (and then class by class)
- Watch the http traffic to ensure all files have been downloaded correctly
- Check to ensure there are no javascript errors

Would be good to if you could share what debugging steps you've already tried.